# Eclipse Android Application project compile with google API 17

Tags: android, eclipse, api, google-api

I only see android api 17 in the selection
I follow the instruction on 
https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-android
But when create a new-->Android Application Project 
In the Compile with: 
I can only select API17 Android 4.2
But the video(at 11:02)has Google API 17!!
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to go into the Android SDK Manager and select `Google API` under Android 4.2.2 and then install the package.

Comment: Installed,but just doesn't appear in the selection

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the appropriate android sdks + Google APIs using the [android sdk manager](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/sdk-manager.html).

Comment: the Google APIs is that the one under Android 4.2(API17) package?if it is,I already installed and I doesn't appear